# Packing Audio Files

Tags: java, opengl, compression, file-format

Hello so I have been working on my own Game and I have a question so right now I am calling my audio files directly for example

```
AudioMaster.loadSound(OsManager.getDirectory() + "theme.WAV");
```

So I was wondering if first have anyone got any recommendations on how I could call the music using an ID like

```
AudioMaster.loadSound(1);
```

put have all of the music packed into one file so I could have 6 music pieces in one file like music.dat or something like that with an extension

Comment: AudioMaster.loadSound is your function?

Comment: @TuyenNguyen yes it is

Comment: @user2574211 pack the files into say a tarball and unpack it at runtime.

Comment: Since this is Java you can easily make them resources in your JAR file. Or put them in another JAR file that you load them from. (And you can call it music.dat if you want, it doesn't have to end in .jar)

Comment: What is `AudioMaster`?

Comment: why OpenGL and Compression tag? without any info about your `AudioMaster` we can only guess ...

Answer (score 0):

You could make loadSound function like:

```
loadSound(int soundId){
     switch(soundId){
     case 1:
      //load what sound you want
     break;
     case 2:
    //load what sound you want
     break;
    }
}
```

Is it what you want?

Comment: No, I should have explained better this is what I meant so saying I have 900 wav files of music i would have 1 file with the 900 music inside then i could all the id and get that music

Comment: I think that you can not do this. A file is not an array or list that you can have index then get which file you want.
A similar solution is: load all your files into a collection, then it have index and you can call which file you want by the index.